# Regular expression problems

Tags: php, regex, quotes

I need some help with some regular expression problems I am having. First off, double quotes `"`.

Anything between `""` needs to be matched. Next problem I need to match anything that starts with a `'` till the end of a line `\n` or `<br />`.

I've tried all sorts, but nothing seems to match it. Any ideas?

Sorry guys, just realised I need the quotes to be between `&quot;` and `&quot;`.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Do matches need to be multi-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

Double quotes:

```
\&quot\;(.*?)\&quot\;
```

Single quote till end of line or `<br/>`:

```
\'(.*)(\<br|$)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplistic:

```
"[^"]*"
```

will match anything between double quotes, though it won't work with escaped double quotes such as

```
"Abc\"Def"
```

For the single-quote to EOL, you can use

```
'.*$
```

**Update:** Sylverdrag's made a valid point; to match between the quotes you'd need

```
"([^"]*)"
```

and then get the first subgroup of the match. I see the question's been updated to mention that `&quot;` should be used - my answer can be adapted to this easily enough.

Comment: This will also match the quotes, though.

Comment: Better, but "([^"]*)" is greedy by default. You must add a ? to get the result you want: "([^"]*?)"

Answer (score 0):

anything between quotes

```
/"(.*)"/
```

from ' till end of line

```
/'(.*)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these regular expressions:

```
/&quot;(.*?)&quot;/s
/'.*?(?=\n|<br \/>)/m
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a bit more funky and match only what is inside the double quotes but not the quotes themselves:

```
(?<=").*?(?=")
```

Comment: Fair enough, but make it ungreedy or there may be some surprises.